# Google Sheets: Query Disappearing when I add a Where Clause

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to write a query function in a sheet I'm working on, but the result is coming up entirely empty. As soon as I remove the where clause, it comes back with no issue.

The query:
`=query('Player Stats'!A2:T20, "select A,B,C where B >= 2 order by C desc limit 5 label A 'NAME', B 'GP', C 'PPG'")`

The range:

[image]

The result:

[image]

I'm confused, frustrated, and have no idea what to do. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

if this wont work:

```
=QUERY('Player Stats'!A2:T20, 
 "select A,B,C 
  where B >= 2 
  order by C desc 
  limit 5 
  label A 'NAME', B 'GP', C 'PPG'", 0)
```

you have a formatting issue where B column (or part of B column) is formatted as plain text